# Using VSCode: How to debug a mono process which is started from another mono process

Tags: c#, debugging, mono, visual-studio-code

I have a process 'a.exe' which I can debug it without any problem.

```
mono --debug --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=127.0.0.1:55555 a.exe
```

The problem occurs when I want to debug a new process ('b.exe') started by 'a.exe' instead of 'a.exe' itself. Here is the code.

```
var startUpInfo = new ProcessStartInfo('b.exe', argumentsOfB);
Process.Start(startUpInfo);
```

I have to pass the same options as above to mono to be able to debug 'b.exe' and use VSCode to attach to the url and port specfied.

The problem is Process.Start() only receives arguments for my exe, not mono.

Is it possible to do this? Or there is another way to solve this?

**My Environment**

- OSX 10.9.5
- Mono 4.0
- VSCode 0.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just passing 'mono' to the ProcessStartInfo and adding all the arguments (mono's debug args, your *.exe, and your program's args) should do the trick. Make sure to use a different port if you want to be able to debug the a.exe and the b.exe.

Comment: what do you mean a 'different port'?

Comment: The VS Code debugger needs to connect to the mono runtime to a 'debug port', that's the '55555' above. If you need to debug more than one runtime process, the mono runtimes must serve different debug ports. So your second runtime could use '55556'. In VS Code one debug session would connect to port '55555' and another session would connect to '55556'.